# Swap image on hover

Tags: php, javascript

Galera, would like to switch from one outfit to another over the mouse, I made one code but is a bit buggy.

I would like this site here: https://amaro.com/moda-feminina/blusas Mine is this: [duetju.com.br](http://duetju.com.br)

My code looks here is:

```
<?php 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$helper = Mage::Helper('catalog/image');
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {} ?>
<img class="<?php if ($alt_img): ?>em-alt-org<?php endif ?>" 
    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($w,$h) ?>" 
    width="<?php echo $w; ?>" 
    height="<?php echo $h ;?>" 
    alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" 
    onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE) ?>';"
    onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE) ?>';"
/>
```

What did is wrong in it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function swap(image) {
         document.getElementById("main").src = image.href;
     }
 </script>
```

```
 <img id="main" src="images/4.jpg" width="50">

 <a href="images/1.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
 <a href="images/2.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a>
 <a href="images/3.jpg" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img src="images/3.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code, however when I checked you item HTML I found that due to `<span class="bkg-hover"></span>` tag which is inserted below your `<img>` tag cause the issue and your hover effect is not properly functional.

Please remove this tag and all goods to go.

Let me know if you have any query.